# my setState() doesn't set the value. How can I fix that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I trying to update my state with setState it doesn't work.

```
sendMax = () => {
    console.log('Balance',this.state.balance)
    this.setState({ amount: this.state.balance })
    console.log('max', this.state.amount)
  }



<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sendMax()}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../../assets/maxIcon.png')}
                  style={styles.icons} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

I'm using it inside of this how can I get this value inside it

when I console this.state.balance I get the value but I cannot set amount with this value

Comment: `setState` is an asynchronous action.

Comment: @Atakan It is not clear what your problem is. Are you saying that when you console log 'max' then the value is the old one and not the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is async, if you want to listen when it's updated, use a callback

`this.setState({ amount: this.state.balance }, () => console.log('max', this.state.amount));`

Comment: sendMax = () => {
    console.log('Balance',this.state.balance)
    this.setState({ amount: this.state.balance },() =>    console.log('max', this.state.amount)
)
  }



<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sendMax()}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../../assets/maxIcon.png')}
                  style={styles.icons} />
              </TouchableOpacity>